# Сохранение value для Audio mixer

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, подскажите как можно сохранить значение `value` для Audio mixer что бы при загрузки загружались сохранные настройки а не дефолтные. Я пытался сохранять через `PlayerPrefs`:

```
public void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("musicVal")) //save Quality
    {
        PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVal");
    }      
}

public void SetMusicLvl(float musicLvl)
{
    masterMixer.SetFloat("musicVal", musicLvl);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVal", musicLvl);
}
```

Но ничего не вышло.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class MixLevels : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioMixer masterMixer;
public Slider slider;

public void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("musicVal")) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVal");
    }        

}

public void SetSfxLvl(float sfxLvl)
{
    masterMixer.SetFloat("sfxVol", sfxLvl);
}

public void SetMusicLvl(float musicLvl)
{
    masterMixer.SetFloat("musicVal", musicLvl);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVal", musicLvl);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вижу как ты достаешь из PlayerPrefs значение, но я не вижу что бы ты пытался это значение куда-то задать.Ну достал ты его, так сделай с ним что-то:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class SoundSettingsSaver : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioMixer masterMixer;

    private float _volume;
    public float Volume
    {
        get
        {
            masterMixer.GetFloat("musicVal", out _volume);

            return _volume;
        }
        set
        {
            _volume = value;
            masterMixer.SetFloat("musicVal", _volume);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVal", _volume);

        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        SettingsVolumeLoad();


        Debug.Log(Volume);

        Volume = 0.9f;

        Debug.Log(Volume); //Здесь мы в логах увидим изменение значения! У меня работает! Урраааа!

    }

    public void SettingsVolumeLoad()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("musicVal"))
        {
            Volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVal");
        }
    }

}
```

UPD1: я немного облегчил тебе задачу еще немного оптимизировав код.

UPD2: твой аудиомиксер нужно еще создать и настроить перед тем как к нему можно будет обращатся по этому коду:

1. Assets -> Create -> Audio Mixer, потом переименуй в MasterMixer
2. потом перетяни мастермиксер в скрипт повешенный на обьект в
   соответствующее поле.
3. А так же не забудь настроить твой миксер так, что бы MasterMixer изменял громкость через параметр "musicVal". Все детальнее по поводу настройки есть в документации, в том числе и в видеоформате:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wWNAiWc8ws

Comment: В коде вопроса есть строка `masterMixer.SetFloat("sfxVol", sfxLvl);` - она и задает значение, ответ не в тему.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker это ты код хреново смотрел. Посмотри на его метод Start(). ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО. А потом сравни с моим методом SettingsVolumeLoad(). А потом снова посмотри на его Start. Вот тебе и ответ "не в тему". Как я и написал: он достает значение с PlayerPrefs но нигде не использует его. Он НЕ передает в мастерМиксер.  **Он нихрена не делает вообще.** Даже во временную переменную не записывает. :) Зато ожидает что что-то случится почему-то.

Comment: Справедливо, не обратил внимание.

Comment: я походу что то не то делаю, value меняет свое значение а в audio mixer не меняет

Comment: я проапдейтил ответ.

Comment: Andrew, спасибо большое за вашу помощь