# Сохранение имени сцены в Json для дальнейшей работы

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос в заголовке. Я уже пробовал через `playerprefs` сейчас я пытаюсь через Json сделать - не выходит.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SaveI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private save saveName = new save();
    private string path; // путь

    public void Start()
    {
       path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "save.json"); //путь
        if (File.Exists(path)) // проверка 
        {
            saveName = JsonUtility.FromJson<save>(File.ReadAllText(path));
            Debug.Log("(" + saveName + " )");
        }               
    }    

    public void checkName(string name)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && name.Length >=3)
        {
            saveName.name = name;
            Debug.Log("sceneName" + name);
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, JsonUtility.ToJson(saveName)); //записует в файл
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class save
    {
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Этот скрипт должен сохранить значение в файл, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было работать с этим значением, и он должен срабатывать одни раз на сцене, но вместо этого запускается каждый раз когда игра уходит на паузу я не знаю как это исправить.

К этому я не понимаю как объединить этот скрипт с этим кодом:

```
Scene name = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); //name scene
Debug.Log("Active scene is  ( " + name.name + " )");
```

По идее все это должно работать так, что второй скрипт выводит имя сцены, а первый скрипт должен сохранить это имя в Json. После сохранения имени в Json должно получиться так, что можно будет использовать сохраненное имя для загрузки уровня, некая система save-load.

Comment: Этот скрипт единственная проблема на данный момент для меня (

Comment: Глупый совет конечно, но вы пробовали найти не готовое решение, в котором вы не разбираетесь, а найти, как работает тот же playerprefs?

Comment: За остальных не могу отвечать, но лично у меня нет желания разбираться в чужом коде, который вы то ли достали черт знает откуда, то ли наугад написали. Для сохранения одной строки использовать JSON - ну такое себе решение.

Comment: Тем более что я там в ответе на тот вопрос писал **робочий код** с сохранением и подгружанием из playerprefs...

Comment: @Andrew предыдущий вопрос закрыли и я не вижу вашего ответа. Если я нужный ответ проверил конечно же. В любом случае есть смысл либо оформить сюда то же решение, либо закрыть, как дубликат.

Comment: а не, прошу прощение, это было не в прошлом вопросе(на прошлый я просто сделал замечание, что вопрос некоректно поставлен). Я показывал практическое применение работы с playerprefs в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916327/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-value-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-audio-mixer .

Comment: @shifu мой личный совет... не как модератора, а как простого пользователя SO: лучше сам удали вопрос и потом востанови и переоформи в другой, какой-то более важный и продуманый. Даст больше шансов позадавать здесь вопросы дольше, а то с таким подходом к задванию вопросов система тебя скоро забанит... А это банально неприятно... **Поверь на слово человеку, которого система банила**

Comment: Планируй результат, больше колупай каждый из путей, который ты нагуглил, обдумуй какой из этих путей лучше. Лучше изучи базу C#. Перечитай FAQ SO о том как задавать вопросы, в конце-концов... Я понимаю что это сложно воспринять сейчас тебе.... Я понимаю что ты новенький в программировании... Но вряд ли кто захочет помогать тебе на КАЖДОМ шагу твоего изучения языка бесплатно на протяжении каждого дня.... Для этого есть учителя в универах или курсах, личные мэнторы...И особенно маловероятно что захочется помогать кому-либо если вопросы задаются в форме как твой прошлый вопрос...

Comment: Человек дело говорит, по метке Unity тут мало кто отвечает, да и отвечают обычно на интересные вопросы, а не "как сделать это, а то мне гугл отключили". Воспринимай это как совет, нам то ни холодно, ни жарко от таких вопросов, тебе же хуже будет от тревог и минусов, а ответа так и не получишь